# need to store date time based on customer timezone

Tags: datetime, timezone, time

1. Is it possible to calculate the timezone based on the country/state field value of a record? If so how?
2. Is it possible to display the time field with the timezone it relates to? If so how?

Comment: 1. Yes.
2. Yes.

Comment: Actually, no for #1.  Several US States have more than one time zone.

Comment: Russia has many timezones

Comment: Have you tried something, looked in the documentation perhaps ?

Comment: where do I start? I know how to format the time but I don't know how to calculate based on the timezone of the record.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes

You can implement a double web service to hit any Geolocation API then any Timezone API. Here is Google's [Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) which will get you a latitude and longitude of City/State combo.  Here is Google's [Timezone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/) which will get you the timezone offset.

2. Yes

Once you store the above offset, you should be able to use the offset to modify any date on a record to account for the offset.

Comment: Unless @Bartley has changed his tune, I'll bet he is looking for a clicks, not code solution :-)